# Opera extension error "Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security violation"

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I am working on an opera extension. The extension have a popup that will open a website in it. 
I get the below error at "xhr.send()" in popup.html file and i can't able to remove it.

> "[4/14/2013 12:51:19 PM] JavaScript -
>   widget://wuid-9ec76e79-06d9-2749-8b7e-b42743de3375/popup.html Inline
>   script thread Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security violation
>   Error thrown at line 30, column 16 in fetchGames() in
>   widget://wuid-9ec76e79-06d9-2749-8b7e-b42743de3375/popup.html:
>       xhr.send(); called from line 32, column 12 in widget://wuid-9ec76e79-06d9-2749-8b7e-b42743de3375/popup.html:
>       fetchGames(); "

My config file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://www.example.org/helloworld">
    <name>Hello Extensions!</name>
    <description>A simple hello world example</description>
    <author href="http://www.twitter.com/dstorey/" email="dstorey@opera.com">David Storey, Opera Software</author>
    <icon src="icons/icon-64.png"/>
</widget>
```

My index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        window.addEventListener( 'load', function(){
            var theButton;
            var ToolbarUIItemProperties = {
                    disabled: false,
                    title: 'Hello World',
                    icon: 'icons/icon-18.png',
                    popup: {
                        href: 'popup.html',
                        width: 500,
                        height: 500
                    }
                }
            theButton = opera.contexts.toolbar.createItem(ToolbarUIItemProperties);
            opera.contexts.toolbar.addItem(theButton);
        }, false );
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

My popup.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
        </style>
        <script>
            function fetchGames() {
            alert('hello');
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xhr.status == 200) {
                            var data = (xhr.responseText);
                            document.getElementById('list_games').innerHTML = data;
                            //callback(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('No Games Found');
                            window.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                var url = 'http://www.anatomic.us/generate-xml';
                xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                xhr.send();
            };
            fetchGames();
            function submitForm(obj)
            {
                var searchKey = document.getElementById('sp').value;
                if(searchKey!=null && searchKey!='')
                {
                    obj.setAttribute('action', 'http://www.3d-game.co/'+searchKey);
                    return true;
//                    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.3d-game.co/'+searchKey});
                }
                else
                    {
                        alert('Please Enter your search item');
                         return false;
                    }

            }
        </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
<!--        <div class="header">
            <a  href="http://www.3d-game.co/"><img src="icon.png"></a>
        </div>
        <br />-->
        <div id=content>
            <div style='padding-left:10px;'>
                <form id=sf method=post action="http://www.3d-game.co/search/" onSubmit="return submitForm(this);" target="_blank">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id=cat_content>
                <div id="list_games" class=list_games>
                <img src="loader.gif" border="none" />
                    <div class="ajax-loader">
                        <img src="loader.gif" border="none" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Plz help me in removing it.

Answer (score 2):

Add following in the header of the file from where you are fetching the data:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0):

in config.xml file add this line:  to allow any domain httprequest before  tab, this solve the problem, if problems persist, open in opera browser tab "opera:config" and select "Users Prefs" and check "Allow File XMLHttpRequest" and restart. if have problem i can send you my opera extension working fine...